# Disable the "You've gone full screen" notification in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I switch into Full Screen (F11) in chrome it says "You've gone full screen. Exit Full Screen (F11)".

Can I disable this from showing up? I know how to exit full screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I make Google Chrome allow fullscreen by default?](http://superuser.com/questions/614797/can-i-make-google-chrome-allow-fullscreen-by-default)

Comment: It is possible to achieve it by injecting assembly code into `chrome.dll` file. Please take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1264349/how-to-completely-remove-press-f11-to-exit-full-screen-chromes-message).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's impossible to suppress this message because this could be a potential security problem (you could fake a desktop and intercept the input of the user).

You could  [search the chromium source](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search) for a flag or something to disable the message. I looked  into a few files with the string "Exit Full Screen" but due to my limited experience in C/C++ I gave up after two minutes.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see the security problem here. 1) The user initiates going full-screen, it's nothing that happens automatically. Why do I need to watch at a box telling me that I pressed F11 after I just actively pressed F11? 2) If the full-screen view would try to fool me and display a desktop which looks like mine I would see the smaller desktop before, since going full-screen  does not change the web page. I don't see a security problem here.

Comment: In some cases, it is possible to expand a window to full screen with JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen - Some users may not understand what's happened, which is a security risk. It used to happen fairly frequently, before newer browsers started adding confirmation steps.

Comment: So then show it, but have a "don't show this again" button or a setting to disable it.  Once you know what you're doing, it's odiously bad UX.

Comment: There should at least be a way to whitelist certain sites. I trust YouTube to use fullscreen responsibly.

Comment: It could just be in the corner and I wouldnt mind, but its in the way !

Comment: You're right, instead I ended up in their godawful Google Product Forums which put me off @ahofmann

Comment: Imagine you're using a web app and you want to go fullscreen, but whenever you move your mouse near the top (where controls may be), you're constantly being told that you've gone fullscreen, and asked to cancel. There should be an option to suppress this message until the page is refreshed.

Comment: chromium-browser --window-size=7000,7000 --start-fullscreen http://google.com --kiosk

Answer (score 20):

This can be accomplished by starting Chrome in kiosk mode.

Here are instructions on how to do this: http://think2loud.com/868-google-chrome-full-screen-kiosk-mode/

> Here are steps for running Google Chrome in full screen Kiosk Mode on
>   a Windows PC:
>
> 1. Right click on your Desktop and go to New > Shortcut
> 2. Browse to the chrome.exe file (depending on how you installed it, it might be in one of these locations:
>
>    - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`
>    - `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`)
>        and click Next
> 3. Type a name for the shortcut (ie “Chrome Kiosk Mode”) and click Finish
> 4. Right click on the new shortcut on your Desktop and go to Properties
> 5. At the end of your Target replace `chrome.exe` with `chrome.exe –kiosk http:// [enter URL here]` and click OK
> 6. Double-click the shortcut on your Desktop and it will launch the full screen Kiosk
> 7. To quit the Kiosk, press Alt + F4 on your keyboard.

Comment: Caveat: this only seems to work if you don't already have a Chrome window open... and once you open one window in kiosk mode, any new windows you open will also go to kiosk mode, even if you open them as a different Chrome user.

Comment: Best workaround if you have other Chrome windows open: http://superuser.com/questions/423272/how-to-make-chrome-open-in-kiosk-mode-even-if-theres-already-another-instance-r

Answer (score 8):

FYI, [here's](http://betanews.com/2014/06/12/banish-annoying-allow-fullscreen-messages-in-google-chrome/) a solution.

As a summary:

- Go to: chrome://settings/contentExceptions#fullscreen
- Replace any existing URL with: `[*.]`

The entry will disappear, but it should still work.

**Source of pattern:** https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3123708?p=settings_manage_exceptions&rd=1

Comment: Hm, the entry disappeared but it's still doing the notification, even after restarting chrome. Wonder if it's been patched out

Comment: What version are you running? It worked on OS X for Chrome 36.

Comment: @BenBrocka Change the pattern to `[*.]`.

Comment: For reference, the original pattern match was: `*://*/*`. Looking at your reference, it doesn't make sense that `[*.]` would work to me. To me, it means that Chrome will optionally match a URL with any characters followed by a period. Maybe this works though.

Comment: Now that I think about it, maybe `*://*` would work better?

Comment: I don't have any entries there.. nothing to edit?

Comment: Looks like you can only remove things from there now, not add. Probably stored in an SQLite DB somewhere, but even so I don't think it will disable the notification, only the allow/deny question.

Comment: On my Chrome, version 46.0.2490.80 m, fullscreen exceptions entries are not editable nor it's possible to enter new ones.

Comment: This does not hide the notification, and therefore does not answer the question. (It only removes the allow/deny prompt.)

Answer (score 1):

Right now it doesn't seem possible in Chrome, but it's super easy in Firefox: visit `about:config`, then enter `full-screen-api.warning.timeout` and set value to 0. Save and enjoy.

Source: https://www.howtogeek.com/659105/how-to-disable-firefoxs-fullscreen-warning-message/