# How to make Chrome open in kiosk mode even if there's already another instance running?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, kiosk

I tried

```
chrome url --kiosk
```

but it works only when there's no instance running. I also tried

```
chrome url --kiosk --new-window
```

but it doesn't solve my problem neither.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/35414/20059), you need to create a new directory and use it for the `user-data-dir`. This should get you started quickly:

```
chrome --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d) --kiosk
```

That will launch an entirely new instance of Crome in kiosk mode. Note the use of `mktemp` above to make a temporary directory. Depending on your goals, you may want to save that to a variable and delete it after Chrome exits.

Comment: On Windows: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=c:\temp --kiosk www.example.com

Answer (score 2):

chrome.exe --chrome-frame -kiosk http://www.google.com

Comment: Give a bit more details what those flags mean, please

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d -t chrome)
```