# Disable "press 'esc' to exit full screen" in flash videos

Tags: flash, notifications, fullscreen, cross-platform, silverlight

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/398945/disable-the-youve-gone-full-screen-notification-in-chrome)

I watch videos on YouTube, Netflix, etc. Whenever I enter full-screen mode, I get the annoying  "You've entered full screen mode. Press 'esc' to exit full screen mode".

Since I'm constantly switching between programs, I see this message a lot and am severely annoyed by it. Is there a way to disable these notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[source](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/304807-How-to-remove-annoying-Press-Esc-to-message-in-Flash-Video)]

For Windows, download and install [this patch](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ssrlsnx1csdyc8p/Flash%20Fullscreen%20Patcher%20v3.00%20%2B%20Source.zip?dl=1) as per the instructions [here](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/304807-How-to-remove-annoying-Press-Esc-to-message-in-Flash-Video)

[For Mac OS X](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/304807-How-to-remove-annoying-Press-Esc-to-message-in-Flash-Video?p=2068945&viewfull=1#post2068945) (requires a windows PC):

1. Goto /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
2. Open* Flash Player.plugin
3. In Flash Player.plugin goto Contents > PlugIns
4. Open* FlashPlayer-{Your Mac OS Version}.plugin (Example: My file was "FlashPlayer-10.4-10.5.plugin" for Mac OS 10.5.5)
5. In FlashPlayer-{Your Mac OS Version}.plugin goto Contents > MacOS
6. Copy FlashPlayer-{Your Mac OS Version} and patch it using the "Other" option in my program on a computer with windows.
7. Copy back the patched FlashPlayer-{Your Mac OS Version} into the folder.

Comment: I feel unconfortable, to say the least, applying a random patch to Flash.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy: I found a few solutions that do not require patching Flash. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For **Firefox** there are a couple of other solutions for this problem, but for *Chrome* I have not been able to find any.

**Note:** The warning is there for security reasons, because sites can otherwise - via JavaScript - automatically fullscreen themselves, and for instance disguise themselves as your desktop, while intercepting user input.
This is particularly an issue as these solutions also disable the first, related popup that *asks* you whether you want to allow or deny the website to put you in fullscreen, not just the notification shown after allowing a site to go into fullscreen.

## Firefox

#### 1: Via about:config

1. Type in `about:config` into the navigation bar and press enter.
2. Search for the value `full-screen-api.approval-required` and set it to **false**.

#### 2: Via a plugin

Install the Firefox plugin [Disable HTML Fullscreen Alert](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disable-html5-fullscreen-alert/?src=ss).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Google Chrome. Would you happen to have instructions for Chrome as well?

Comment: You're right, it's not a general solution, though I expect looking into browser specific solutions is in general a good idea. I have found some suggestions for Chrome, like `kiosk mode` and white- isting all websites to go into fullscreen, but the first seemed to make no difference, and the second will only disable the popup asking for approval, not the notifications afterwards.