# How to stop the "Close fullscreen with ESC" popup window in videos?

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube, fullscreen

My current problem with YouTube and other video systems are their constant popups, when I resize the video screen, intentionally or - more often - unintentionally:
[image: YouTube Fullscreen popup]
[image: Creativelive Fullscreen popup]

*(sorry for the German...)*

What I want to, is to **block** - or remove by keystroke - these overlays. Is there any option to do this?
In Google Chrome preferably, but I might as well switch to another browser at times, if there would be a solution that is only possible within e.g. Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable "press 'esc' to exit full screen" in flash videos](http://superuser.com/questions/485208/disable-press-esc-to-exit-full-screen-in-flash-videos). Also see [Disable the “You've gone full screen” notification in Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/398945/disable-the-youve-gone-full-screen-notification-in-chrome).

Comment: How does one resize a fullscreen video "window"?