# Flash is now full screen press ESC to exit

Tags: flash, fullscreen, popups

Really annoying "advice" while using flash software in full screen.

[image: prezi]

Even when you have selected to allow full-screen this popup will occur. Kind of a drawback in presentation software.

[image: popup]

There is another, similar question here about flash video
[Disable "press 'esc' to exit full screen" in flash videos](https://superuser.com/questions/485208/disable-press-esc-to-exit-full-screen-in-flash-videos)
But the link that the answer provides no longer exists.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with Prezi as much as it does Adobe Flash. I did not have any issues following the links in the solution you posted. They resolve just fine.

Comment: Perhaps. If anyone knows how to resolve this for Flash in general, I would be much obliged. 

As for the link, I quote: "vBulletin Message
Invalid Attachment specified. If you followed a valid link, please notify the administrator"