# Can I make Google Chrome allow fullscreen by default?

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

On [the Google Chrome permissions page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?p=ui_security_indicator&rd=1), it says that you can change Fullscreen permissions.

However, when clicking the permissions, I can only change to allow *on this page* or ask:

[image]

I want to be able to always allow on any site, like some other permissions have:

[image]

Is this possible? I also want to get rid of this:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EDIT: I found out the reason Chrome prompts is because this is a security issue where [sites could possibly impersonate](http://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/y4cvg/is_now_fullscreen_well_no_kidding_i_clicked/) a browser environment.

I got it to work on my machine by using Google's [host pattern matching](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

1. Open Chrome's Content extensions paste this into an address bar: chrome://settings/contentExceptions#fullscreen
2. Edit an item to be `*://*/*` and save (on my machine it disappeared from the list but worked the way I wanted.) (per @Jaex comment below try just * I used both, but I tried the * first and assumed it didn't work when it disappeared from my list.)

Thats it, it worked immediately for me.

Comment: I used just `*` and it worked fine.

Comment: When it disappears from the list, I wonder how you can revert. Maybe through a config file somewhere?

Comment: It's not possible to edit anymore, just to delete (MAC OS on Chrome 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit))

Comment: It's not possible to edit because this list is no longer used.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on windows just edit your Chrome shortcut properties:

Where it says target:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

add `--kiosk` to the end

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk
```

It will now run in full screen mode each time you start it.

Comment: Sweet, do you know of a way to get rid of the "You have gone full screen" message?

Comment: From what I know it's not possible to remove that message for now. Could be available in one of the next updates though since people are demanding to remove it.